# Need batch file help to pull data from a text file, separated by a bunch of |||

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm running windows vista and I need some help to write a batch program to pull out some data from a text file, so that I can generate another text file with the data in a specific format

The problem is that the text file data is separated by a bunch of |||| and I don't know how to remove or read the data between them.

Here's a sample of the data file:

```
MMM|^~\&|SSS||||20130813084347||RUR|14864-1W2220300-9|P^|2.3.0|||NE|ER
PID|||2013-1W2220300|-|LASTNAME^FIRSTNAME^||19971101|F|||||(416)222-3888||||||X2861673469 HY
```

and here's the output file that I need to generate.

```
currentdate  currenttime  REC   F  M  1W2220300  2861673469  HY  LASTNAME  FIRSTNAME 14864  13-AUG-2013  08:43:47
```

The "REC" "F" and "M" variables don't change, but the others do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, as my knowledge of batch files is pretty limited.

Comment: Have you shown two lines that represent one record of data?  To begin with it is not clear where the `1W2220300` comes from because it is in two places.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=4,6,13,17,18 delims=|" %%a in (t.t) do (echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e)` should give you a good starting point. Your next problems would be the proper formatting of the date-time-string (%%a) to your needs and separating LASTNAME from FIRSTNAME (%%c)

Answer (score 1):

solution for [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
sed "y/|/ /" file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  q18241872.txt
  ) DO (
  SET "var=%%a"
  SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
   SET var=!var:^|=^| !
   ECHO !var!
  ENDLOCAL 

 )
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

This should produce `newfile.txt` from your original file which I've arbitrarily named `q18241872.txt`.

The new file should have each `|` separated by a space (nothing magical about space, could be any character within reason - `@` perhaps...) and you would then be able to process further using `FOR/F "tokens=...delims=|" ...` but since you give no clue as to the actual structure of your source nor the processing required to produce your desired output, that's where I'll have to leave it...